# Apply click event automatically to every HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I would like to apply the `click` event (or any other event) **automatically** to **every HTML element** on the page.

I am developing kind of a "clicking game" and would like to use **one generic JavaScript function** that will handle every click on every HTML element on the page.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: By "apply", do you mean "handle"?

Comment: jQuery has hijacked the term `bind` to mean something entirely different, and confusing to those who don't know the terminology. The correct term is "attach an event handler".

Answer (score 3):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}, false);
```

the `e.target` will give you the element that has been clicked.

Comment: Is it possible to pass "this" HTML element to the function? I mean for example: <p onClick="foo(this);"></p> - so the P element is passed to the function. Or I should use tagName / localName attributes?

Answer (score 3):

It's not only possible, it's trivial:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Use e.target for the clicked element
}, false);
```

Clicks "bubble" from the clicked element to its parent, then its parent, then its parent, etc., until they reach the document. (Unless an intervening event handler stops that via `e.stopPropagation`.) The above hooks the click on `body` (the container of all of your visible elements).

Note that the above works on all modern browsers, including IE9 and up *in standards mode*. It does not work on IE8 and earlier (or IE9 and later pretending to be IE8 or earier) because they didn't have `addEventListener`. You'd have to use the IE-specific `attachEvent` instead.

Comment: Why not bind directly the event on the document instead of the body? Does it changes anything?

Comment: `Clicks "bubble" from the clicked element to its parent, then its parent, then its parent, etc., until they reach the document.` unless event bubbling is prevented using `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Tushar: `return false` only does that under jQuery, but yes, unless propagation is stoppped by an intervening handler.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just found you already answered my question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029340/jquery-event-handling-bind-to-document-or-body-element

Comment: @Tushar: "Clicks bubble" is correct, not "Click bubble". I also refer to functions by their names, without `()`, and meant "document" as a word, not a symbol.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was thinking about `click bubbles`