# JQuery: document versus body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

if I use:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary someClassName">Test</>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("document").on("click", '.someClassName', function () {
        alert('click');       
    });
});
```

If I click the link, it doesn't do anything.

However, if I change it to:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary someClassName">Test</>
```

```js
$(body).ready(function () {
    $("document").on("click", '.someClassName', function () {
        alert('click');       
    });
});
```

Then the alert is displayed.

So my question is: why does `$("document").on()` not work, and why does `$("body").on()` work?

Comment: because 'document' is not HTML element whereas 'body' is..!

Comment: you can view detailed statement about it here http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307112/difference-between-document-body-and-body-jquery

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, but the answer is indeed found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307112/difference-between-document-body-and-body-jquery. Thanks for the answers, it was indeed something I simply looked over :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'document'` is a element selector, and there is no element with tagname `document`

```
$(document)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because when you pass a string to the selector jQuery uses the sizzle selector engine to search for that element within the DOM. So you are looking for a `<document />` element, which obviously will not exist.

The correct syntax is to use `$(document)`; note the lack of quotes. jQuery then uses the `document` object as the parent selector.