# jQuery selector in bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Seems I have a problem using jQuery when I try to select an element included in a div with a bootstrap class.

The code is this:

```
    <div class="sec">
  <div class="dropdown">
        <h4>Management</h4><hr>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Staff <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" data-intrf="dir-01-01" >List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-intrf="dir-01-02">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-intrf="dir-01-03">Categories</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-intrf="dir-01-04">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
</div></div>
```

jQuery code is:

```
$('#secInterf').on("click", 'a[data-intrf]', function(){
        alert('What Ever');
});
```

The html code (div with class="sec") is placed as dynamic content within a div (with id="secInterf") in the main page.
The problem is that it seems that jQuery can no recognize the anchor with attribute data-intrf.

I had no problem with other dynamic content placed in the same div (#secInterf); so, I don't know if it's some kind of conflict between jQuery and Bootstrap or if I'm using a wrong selector to get the anchor with attribute data-intrf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dynamic content may provide problems when trying to access something that simply isn't there yet. Perhaps an if statement to make sure the selected content exists?

Comment: You could try to write $(document.body).on(.. and so on instead of $('#secInterf').on(..

Comment: @MichaelTroger the code is just fine in the OP

Comment: @MichaelTroger : It works fine when using `$('body').on("click", 'a[data-intrf]', function(){
   getInterfaceData( $(this).attr('data-intrf') );
  });` Thanks!!

Comment: @MatCat I'm glad I could help. I added my answer, please accept it if you think it has been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to exchange the first selector like:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a[data-intrf]', function(){ 
   alert('What Ever'); }
);
```

**Explanation:**
As you didn't share the full code but just an except I can just speculate but a possible reason why selecting it by `#secInterf` didn't work for you is that the element was **not there on the initial page load** (you inserted it dynamically too).

Using *body* or *document* as the first selector for delegated events should always work. It's just not best practice as you should just try to use a selector closer to your dynamic element because of performance reasons as also stated here: https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

**EDIT:** As the OP stated it worked for him using the *$('body')* selector.
Which is actually doing the same as the selector above. The difference is just a performance difference and in detail explained here [Difference between $(document.body) and $('body') JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307112/difference-between-document-body-and-body-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

trying to use this code ..

`$(document).on('click','#Selector' function(){
console.log('What you want '); //it's better then alert (i think).
});`